# VueJS 3 axios can't get data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm newbie in VueJS 3 and I'm learning Composition API. I've made a weather website but can't get data. This is my function

```
setup() {
    let weather = reactive({});

    async function getData() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
                const API_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=60acb662839f9a6279f91ef167a37b9f`;
                let res = await axios.get(API_URL);
                return res.data;
            });
        }
    }
    onMounted(() => {
        getData()
            .then(data => {
                weather = data;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));   
    });

    return weather;
},
```

It seem a asynchronous error. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line -

```js
weather = data;
```

You override your weather object, so it looses reactivity.

You should add properties to the original object, not override it:

```js
Object.assign(weather, data)
```

So the correct code should be:

```js
setup() {
    const state = reactive({});

    async function fetchData() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
          const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=60acb662839f9a6279f91ef167a37b9f`;
          const {data} = await axios.get(API_URL);
          state.weather = data
        });
      }
    }

    fetchData()

    return {
      state
    };
}
```

And in your template:

```html
<template>
  {{state.weather}}
</template>
```

Comment: @studyandroid I edited the answer to add the full code example, try that please.

Comment: still the same, just get data in fetchData function, otherwise is not. Does it a asynchronous error ?

Comment: Here is working JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5shtp0Lq/.

Edited answer once again.

Comment: yeah it worked, but i don't understand why doesn't it work with axios?

Comment: It's not actually axios problem. You might want to read [Vue composition api introduction](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#api-introduction). If you have any problems, let me know and I will invite you to chat room.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work

```
 setup() {
    let weather = reactive({});

    async function getData() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
          const API_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=60acb662839f9a6279f91ef167a37b9f`;
          const res = await axios.get(API_URL);
          weather = res.data;
        });
      }
    }
    onMounted(() => {
      getData();
    });

    return { weather };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let states = reactive({"items": ""});
let cities = reactive({"items": ""});
```

then

```
$(document.body).on("change", "#default_address_country_id", function () {
    memberNewData.default_address_country_id = this.value;

    if (this.value) {
        callStateApi(this.value)
            .then(data => {
                states.items = data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                toast.error(err)
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    $('#default_address_state_id').prop("disabled", false);
    console.log(states);
});
```

then

```
$(document.body).on("change", "#default_address_state_id", function () {
    memberNewData.default_address_state_id = this.value


    if (this.value) {
        callCityApi(this.value)
            .then(data => {
                cities.items = data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                toast.error(err)
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    $('#default_address_city_id').prop("disabled", false);
    console.log(cities);
});
```

then

```
function callStateApi(countryId) {
    const promise = axios.get('/api/state/' + countryId)
    return promise.then((response) => response.data)
}

function callCityApi(stateId) {
    const promise = axios.get('/api/city/' + stateId)
    return promise.then((response) => response.data)
}
```

then this as html

```
<div class="row mt-6">
    <div class="col-6">

        <h5 class="required ">State</h5>
        <select v-model="memberNewData.default_address_state_id"
                class="form-select form-select-transparent min-h-45px"
                id="default_address_state_id" disabled>
            <option></option>
            <option v-for="option in states.items" :value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

        <h5 class="required ">City</h5>
        <select v-model="memberNewData.default_address_city_id"
                class="form-select form-select-transparent min-h-45px"
                id="default_address_city_id" disabled>
            <option></option>
            <option v-for="option in cities.items" :value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```